# Face unlock and sun glasses

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, face-unlock

I'm thinking about getting new glasses, the kind that get dark(like sun glasses) or clear depending on the amount of light they get so they are supposed to be dark in the outside and clear inside.

I think my actual question is: can you set up Android face unlock to work with "sun glasses"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this will probably be less secure than using your face...

i suggest using a password for maximum security !

Comment: It sounds like you're guessing. We prefer credible answers, drawing from demonstrated expertise or official sources. Could you [edit] your answer to add some reasoning or source, rather than a flat claim.